# Swiper.js in prestashop - hide other images

Tags: javascript, image, prestashop, swiper.js

I'm trying to add swiper to prestashop. The swiper works but I have one small problem. Other images in slider are displayed and I want to hide them. Been searching from yesterday and can't find what I need. I'm a newbie with coding but I managed to get it work with this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade js-product-images-modal" id="product-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="swiper-container " style="width:100%">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        {foreach from=$product.images item=image}
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
            <img src="{$image.bySize.large_default.url}" alt="{$image.legend}" style="width:100%;" title="{$image.legend}" itemprop="image">
          </div>
        </div>
        {/foreach}
      </div>
      <!-- Add Pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>  

<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
    });
</script>
```

Swiper looks like this now:

https://i.ibb.co/c2D8QPx/Swiper-preview.png

So I want to hide other images on the right, is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, wrong 'swiper-container' in swiper 7 it should just be 'swiper'. Working very well now :)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade js-product-images-modal" id="product-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="swiper" style="width:100%">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        {foreach from=$product.images item=image}
        <div class="swiper-slide">
           <img src="{$image.bySize.large_default.url}" alt="{$image.legend}" style="width:100%;" title="{$image.legend}" itemprop="image">
        </div>
        {/foreach}
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>  
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    spaceBetween: 30,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
    },
    keyboard: true,
    effect: "fade",
    });
</script>
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Posting if someone wants to use it :) added effect fade and keyboard shifting